# Creating First Application of Flex "How to Change Button label", learning resources for Flex from Flash background

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I'm just getting started switching from flash to flex for the better components. I am trying the simple experiment of adding a button and then changing the label. This code does not work. It does not recognize myButton. In flash I could access a button instance after adding it using the instance name. Can't you do this in flex?
Thanks

```
<s:Button x="50" y="42" label="Button" id="myButton"/>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
    myButton.label="winning";
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex have an *Event based structure* you can not just put command/expression in script block
it should be wrapped in function

like

```
private function changelabel():Void
{
 myButton.label="winning"; 
}
```

and you need to call this function on an event like **Click** event of Button as

```
<s:Button x="50" y="42" label="Button" id="myButton" click="{changelabel()}"/>
```

You should read [Migrating a Flash application to Flex](http://aralbalkan.com/downloads/FlashToFlex.pdf)

and to take a look in Flex you should vist [Flex Developer Center](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex.html)

Hopes that helps

Comment: Actually, you *can* put code in Script block without function, but this has little sense in MXML. This code is executed when component is created, and its children not exist yet.

Comment: The code above does not work. But this code does.<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
      xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
      xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
 <fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[

   function changelabel()
   {
    myButton.label="winning"; 
   }

  ]]>
 </fx:Script>
 <s:Button x="50" y="42" label="Button" id="myButton" click="changelabel()"/>

</s:Application>